# How to create a virtual machine from several .zip files?

Tags: virtualbox

I need to install in my virtualBox a Ubuntu machine that was split and compressed in 4 folder, each containing a Ubuntu.vdi and a Ubuntu.vbox file.

What should I do?

Comment: Please describe how exactly the ZIP archive was made. Is it really not a regular multi-volume archive?

Comment: Unfortunally the person who compressed the file didn't make available any information regarding that. But if it's a multi-volume archive what should I do?

Comment: @DanielB could you please offer me some help?

Comment: There's not really enough information. I'd suggest inspecting the contents of the vbox files (and sharing the storage specific part of it), and the file extentions of the ubuntu machines.